# OS X can't detect serial ports in Terminal with screen command

Tags: java, macos, serial-port

Screen command in OS X does not detect any connected USB devices except Bluetooth ports.

Finally I need to create serial communication between 2 Java applications on OS X and first create 2 virtual serial ports with socat:

```
./socat -d -d tty tty
```

The output is:

```
N PTY is /dev/ttys000
N PTY is /dev/ttys001
N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

then I create two symbolic links with

```
ln -s /dev/ttys000 /dev/ttyUSB01
ln -s /dev/ttys001 /dev/ttyUSB02
```

The problem is when I try to make Java detect the serial ports to start communication, none of these is detected. Moreover when I connect a USB device and try to get all serial ports with the command screen it shows only Bluetooth ports.